# Why won't windows remember their size in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, window-management

If I close a window, I expect it to remember the size it was, and reopen the same size next time.

On Lubuntu, this isn't happening.  I close a window, and the next time I open that app, the window might be small, big, or as big as the screen, but not maximized.

Is this a Linux thing?  Is it the window manager, or the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is both a Window manager and an application-specific thing. Window managers such as Compiz are able to remember the size of your windows and open them in the last used sized if setup correctly. However, on Lubuntu, the Window Manager is Openbox, which does not support this feature.

Some applications handle this themselves, and some even have it in their preferences. If you really *need* this feature you can use Compiz. However, most Compiz features require compositing (in 3D), so your hardware needs to support it.

Comment: i verified this by reading a post on the openbox ML from 2004.http://icculus.org/pipermail/openbox/2004-March/002348.html